# Using same Google Adsense units for web and mobile versions

Tags: google-adsense, mobile, browsers, responsive-webdesign

I'm redesigning a website. This time it will be responsive, so that the same pages that are loaded into a desktop browser will be loaded in mobile browsers as well.

The question is: can I use the same adsense units from both desktop and mobile platforms? Or do I have to configure special Google Adsense for Mobile units?

Thanks

Comment: You are now allowed to create a script which will load the correct adsense unit (e.g. small for mobile, larger one for desktop) when the page loads (but you cannot change them when the page is resized).

Comment: thanks for the tip. I've been looking around for solutions, it seems that there is this beta ad unit available for some publishers, called Responsive Unit. It will automatically deliver the right size for the current viewport.